# Converting to Ascii fails at &

Tags: java, encoding, sms

We have a java application which sends sms. We have 2 two variable set as below.Then it goes through an encoding process. The problem now it works fine but after the &Time.... the message is not delivered? So what other encoding mechanism should I work on?

```
String smsMessage = "Asset:TEST1\nSerial ID:Test1\nEvent:Arrive\nDate&Time:2012-04-26 21:06:37\nEvent Location:Location1";
String fullMessageLink="user=tt1&password=tt11&api_id=2211&to=1234567&text="+smsMessage;

URI uri = new URI(
        "http", 
        "api.clickatell.com", 
        "/http/sendmsg",
        fullMessageLink,
        null);

 String request = uri.toASCIIString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ampersand `&` is used as the separator between URL parameters.  Notice the `&'s` in the `fullMessageLink`.  To pass a string with an `&` it is you need to [URL encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the value.

Use the [URLEncoder class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to perform the encoding.

Comment: so I did this smsMessage = URLEncoder.encode(smsMessage, "UTF-8"); but unfortunately when I receive the sms is with all the % in the message. So how to overcome this ya?

Comment: @user837306 - No clue, even their FAQ says that is what you should do: http://support.clickatell.com/faq.php?mode=view_entry&kbid=213&kbcat=28

Comment: @sh301 Here is the encoded message &text=Asset%253ATEST1%250ASerial+ID%253ATest1%250AEvent%253AArrive%250ADate%2526Time%253A2012-04-26+21%253A06%253A37%250AEvent+Location%253ALocation1 their line break is %0A but when I use \n is get %250A do you think this could be a problem too?

Comment: @user837306 That looks like it is double URL encoded.  The `:` after Asset should encode to `%3A` then encoding that twice would that would encode the % to `%25` making the string `%253a`

Comment: @user837306 just use a httpclient library for this, it is easy.

Comment: @sh301 I think I am removing this uri.toASCIIString(); and just run the urlencode for the actual message and it works now.